# createprocess doesn't inherit parent env

Tags: c++, shell, cygwin

I have written the following code to create a process on cygwin that run a script

```
DWORD RunSilent(char* strFunct, char* strstrParams)
{
STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo;
char Args[4096];
char *pEnvCMD = NULL;
char *pDefaultCMD = "CMD.EXE";
ULONG rc;

memset(&StartupInfo, 0, sizeof(StartupInfo));
StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
StartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
StartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

Args[0] = 0;


strcat(Args, strFunct);  
strcat(Args, " "); 
strcat(Args, strstrParams); 
if (!CreateProcess( NULL, Args, NULL, NULL, TRUE,
    /*CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, */
    0,
    NULL, 
    NULL,
    &StartupInfo,
    &ProcessInfo))
{
    return GetLastError();      
}

WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
if(!GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess, &rc))
    rc = 0;

CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);

return rc;

}

int main(){
RunSilent("c:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe", " --login -i -c \"/cygdrive/c/FP/V7/myscript \"");
return 0;
}
```

the content of myscript is :

```
if test $MY_HOME
    then
    FORMALHOME_HOME=$MY_HOME
    export FORMALHOME_HOME
else
    echo "A Home variable is required: missing \$MY_HOME"
    exit -1
fi
```

by running my program it always returns the message  "A Home variable is required: missing $MY_HOME"
Although the variable $MY_HOME already set

seems that the created process doesn't inherit the parent environment

Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves all of your problem, but the `--login`-option of `bash` clears all environment variables and provides a clean shell. Have you tried leaving out this option?

Comment: I removed it but problem still exist